# Backup of Sandbox before refresh

Tags: sandbox, sandbox-refresh, backup

I am new to salesforce.Recently i have created an application in salesforce Preprod instance which includes both standard and custom objects and created custom fields and some validation rules too.

Now,one of my colleagues is planning to refresh that sandbox.I do not know how to take backup of that app and respective metadata.

Can anyone help me out with the steps how to take backup and how to load back after sandbox refresh.

Your response would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are various tools available  which you can take help from

1. MavensMate - http://www.infallibletechie.com/2015/12/mavensmate-forcecom-ide-installation.html
2. ANT - http://www.infallibletechie.com/2014/06/ant-setup-for-salesforce-migration.html
3. Eclipse - Force.com IDE - https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation

   - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ide_install.htm

With the help of these you can take offline backup and then once SB is refresh you can upload your changes back in the system.

My suggestion you should go with Eclipse or Mavens Mate because they are easy to configure.

For the data you can use SF native Data export wizard to export all data in system. Then use Data loader, Data Import Wizard or Dataloader.io to import data again in the system.

Answer (score 1):

If you have another sandbox ,you can use changeset to back up all the components .

You will need to use dataloader to extract all data files if you need to restore data.

There are other tools like eclipse IDE and Force.com migration tool but to begin with use changeset as they are relatively simple to use .